# Vulkan line drawing not showing up

Tags: rendering, vulkan, renderdoc

So I would like to render the bounding box of a selected object.  I have a buffer to store the 8 points and another buffer to store the indices to use line strip drawing of those points to make a box.  I captured a frame with RenderDoc and I can see the yellow box [bounding box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ClGB.png)[image: box with rest of scene]

So it looks like the values are correct and the box is being drawn, but I do not see it in the final render to the screen.[image: final scene].  Anyone have an idea what I might be missing here?

```
    VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding cameraBind = vkinit::descriptorset_layout_binding(VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER, VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT, 0);

    VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo setinfo = {};
    setinfo.bindingCount = 1;
    setinfo.flags = 0;
    setinfo.pNext = nullptr;
    setinfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
    setinfo.pBindings = &cameraBind;

    vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout(_device, &setinfo, nullptr, &_globalSetLayout);

    //setup push constant
    VkPushConstantRange push_constant;
    push_constant.offset = 0;
    push_constant.size = sizeof(glm::mat4);
    push_constant.stageFlags = VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT;

    VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo mesh_pipeline_layout_info = vkinit::pipeline_layout_create_info();
    mesh_pipeline_layout_info.setLayoutCount = 1;
    mesh_pipeline_layout_info.pSetLayouts = &_globalSetLayout;
    mesh_pipeline_layout_info.pPushConstantRanges = &push_constant;
    mesh_pipeline_layout_info.pushConstantRangeCount = 1;

    vkCreatePipelineLayout(_device, &mesh_pipeline_layout_info, nullptr, &_highlightPipelineLayout);

    PipelineBuilder highlightPipelineBuilder;

    VertexInputDescription description;
    VkVertexInputBindingDescription mainBinding = {};
    mainBinding.binding = 0;
    mainBinding.stride = sizeof(glm::vec3);
    mainBinding.inputRate = VK_VERTEX_INPUT_RATE_VERTEX;
    description.bindings.push_back(mainBinding);

    //Position will be stored at Location 0
    VkVertexInputAttributeDescription positionAttribute = {};
    positionAttribute.binding = 0;
    positionAttribute.location = 0;
    positionAttribute.format = VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32_SFLOAT;
    positionAttribute.offset = 0;

    description.attributes.push_back(positionAttribute);

    highlightPipelineBuilder._pipelineLayout = _highlightPipelineLayout;
    highlightPipelineBuilder.vertexDescription = description;
    highlightPipelineBuilder._inputAssembly = vkinit::input_assembly_create_info(VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINE_STRIP);
    highlightPipelineBuilder._rasterizer = vkinit::rasterization_state_create_info(VK_POLYGON_MODE_LINE);
    highlightPipelineBuilder._depthStencil = vkinit::depth_stencil_create_info(true, true, VK_COMPARE_OP_ALWAYS);

    ShaderEffect* lineEffect = new ShaderEffect();
    lineEffect->add_stage(_shaderCache.get_shader(shader_path("wk_highlight.vert.spv")), VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT);
    lineEffect->add_stage(_shaderCache.get_shader(shader_path("wk_highlight.frag.spv")), VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT);
    lineEffect->reflect_layout(_device, nullptr, 0);

    highlightPipelineBuilder.setShaders(lineEffect);

    _highlightPipeline = highlightPipelineBuilder.build_pipeline(_device, _renderPass);
```

and here is the drawing part

```
        vkCmdBindPipeline(cmd, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, _highlightPipeline);

        uint32_t camera_data_offset = _dynamicData.push(_camera.matrices);
        VkDescriptorBufferInfo camInfo = _dynamicData.source.get_info();
        camInfo.range = sizeof(GPUCameraData);
        camInfo.offset = camera_data_offset;

        VkDescriptorSet cameraSet;
        vkutil::DescriptorBuilder::begin(_descriptorLayoutCache, _dynamicDescriptorAllocator)
            .bind_buffer(0, &camInfo, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER, VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT)
            .build(cameraSet);

        vkCmdPushConstants(cmd, _highlightPipelineLayout, VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT, 0, sizeof(glm::mat4), &_selectedMatrix);

        VkDeviceSize offset = 0;
        vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(cmd, 0, 1, &_highlightVertexBuffer._buffer, &offset);
        vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(cmd, _highlightIndexBuffer._buffer, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT16);

        vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(cmd, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, _highlightPipelineLayout, 0, 1, &cameraSet, 0, nullptr);

        vkCmdDrawIndexed(cmd, 16, 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

And the shaders

```
#version 450
layout (location = 0) in vec3 vPosition;

layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform  CameraBuffer{   
    mat4 view;
    mat4 proj;
    mat4 viewproj;
} cameraData;

layout(push_constant) uniform PushConstants {
    mat4 matrix;
} pushConstants;

void main() 
{   
    mat4 modelMatrix = pushConstants.matrix;
    mat4 transformMatrix = (cameraData.viewproj * modelMatrix);
    gl_Position = transformMatrix * vec4(vPosition, 1.0f);
}
```

fragment shader

```
//glsl version 4.5
#version 450

//output write
layout (location = 0) out vec4 outFragColor;

void main() 
{   
    outFragColor  = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: You should add at least the relevant parts of your rendering code (pipeline setup, drawing, etc.). Without that, it's nearly impossible to find out why your line is not showing up.

Comment: Thanks Sascha - appreciate your work by the way as that is where I started with this!  I've added the setup code and drawing code along with the shaders.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find out the solution?